# jQuery Virtual keyboard are saving value from previous input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work with Virtual keyboar, and i have issues.

Issues is, in one UI i have few **input fields** for each of this field i have **class "input"** which call key board.

When i tap for first input and enter data, this data which was for previous input field are copie to new.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".numpad").hide();
    $('.input').click(function () {
        $('.numpad').fadeToggle('fast');
    });

    $('.del').click(function () {
        $('.input').val($('.input').val().substring(0, $('.input').val().length - 1));
    });
    $('.faq').click(function () {
        alert("It's virtual keyboard");
    })
    $('.shuffle').click(function () {
        $('.input').val($('.input').val() + $(this).text());
    });

});

$(".input").on("click", function () {
    $('.modal, .cover').removeClass("hidden");
    $('.modal').addClass("zoom");
});

//hide modal
$(".cover, .close").on("click", function () {
    $('.modal').attr('class', 'modal');
    $('.modal, .cover').addClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.keyBoardButton {
    margin: 13px;
}

.keyBoardButton {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 20px 27px;
    background-color: #878787;
}

    .keyBoardButton:hover, .keyBoardButton:active {
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

.cover {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .9;
}

.modal {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 390px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #262626;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: solid 3px #262626;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.9;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

    .modal .content p {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #fff;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

.tiltup {
    display: block;
    transform: perspective(300px);
    animation: tiltup 0.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    padding-top: 0;
}

@keyframes tiltup {
    0% {
        bottom: -400px;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotateX(-80deg);
        border-top: solid 40px;
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

.zoom {
    display: block;
    animation: zoom 0.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0, 0);
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.reverse {
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">

<div class='cover hidden'></div>
<div class='modal hidden'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class="numpad">
            <div id="container">
                <div>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">1</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">2</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">3</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">4</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">5</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">6</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">7</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">8</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">9</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="del keyBoardButton">X</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">0</button>
                    <button class="faq keyBoardButton">?</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

So as you can see, when click in to input field, Virtual keyboard are opening in modal window, after addind data, at other input fileds this data will copie.

So for each input i need separate data.

Comment: you should fill input only which got clicked. dnt use each loop.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra can you provide some example?

Answer (score 1):

**See this snippest, you will get some idea.**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

 var selected_inp;
    $(".numpad").hide();
    $('.input').click(function () {
       selected_inp = $(this);
        $('.numpad').fadeToggle('fast');
    });

    $('.del').click(function () {
        $('.input').val($('.input').val().substring(0, $('.input').val().length - 1));
    });
    $('.faq').click(function () {
        alert("It's virtual keyboard");
    })
    $('.shuffle').click(function () {
        //$('.input').val($('.input').val() + $(this).text());
        selected_inp.val($(this).text());
    });
    (function ($) {

        $.fn.shuffle = function () {

            var allElems = this.get(),
                getRandom = function (max) {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
                },
                shuffled = $.map(allElems, function () {
                    var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                        randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                    allElems.splice(random, 1);
                    return randEl;
                });

            this.each(function (i) {
                $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
            });

            return $(shuffled);

        };

    })(jQuery);

});

$(".input").on("click", function () {
    $('.modal, .cover').removeClass("hidden");
    $('.modal').addClass("zoom");
});

//hide modal
$(".cover, .close").on("click", function () {
    $('.modal').attr('class', 'modal');
    $('.modal, .cover').addClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.keyBoardButton {
    margin: 13px;
}

.keyBoardButton {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 20px 27px;
    background-color: #878787;
}

    .keyBoardButton:hover, .keyBoardButton:active {
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

.cover {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .9;
}

.modal {
    z-index: 2;
    height: 390px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #262626;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: solid 3px #262626;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.9;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

    .modal .content p {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #fff;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

.tiltup {
    display: block;
    transform: perspective(300px);
    animation: tiltup 0.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    padding-top: 0;
}

@keyframes tiltup {
    0% {
        bottom: -400px;
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotateX(-80deg);
        border-top: solid 40px;
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

.zoom {
    display: block;
    animation: zoom 0.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0, 0);
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.reverse {
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">

<div class='cover hidden'></div>
<div class='modal hidden'>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class="numpad">
            <div id="container">
                <div>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">1</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">2</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">3</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">4</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">5</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">6</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">7</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">8</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">9</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="del keyBoardButton">X</button>
                    <button class="shuffle keyBoardButton">0</button>
                    <button class="faq keyBoardButton">?</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Working at same way, when you add data to new field, it's copie fro previus

Comment: Did you block quantity of entered symbols?

Comment: no, and its just demo purpose so you can get idea, you can change code as per your need.